# replace word that are in a list for every row with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this list of words:

```
word = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
```

And this dataframe:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['big dog', 'good food', 'dog and cat', 'little fish', 'intense light', 'nice cat']})
```

I'd like to replace the text in my word list when it appears in my dataframe column. I've tried doing this:

```
for row in dfa['a']:
   for w in word:
       if w in row:
           dfa['a'] = dfa['a'].replace(w, "animal")
```

I'm not getting any error. But it just doesn't work

This is what I'd like to have in the end:

```
    a
big animal
good food
animal and animal
little animal
intense light
nice animal
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over the words to replace instead of each row for each word. Note the `regex` argument, which will allow finding and replacing of substrings. You can find the more information in the docs for `pandas.DataFrame.replace` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

```
import pandas as pd


word = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['big dog', 'good food', 'dog and cat', 'little fish', 'intense light', 'nice cat']})

for w in word:
    dfa = dfa.replace(w, "animal", regex=True)

print(dfa)
```

This outputs

```
                   a
0         big animal
1          good food
2  animal and animal
3      little animal
4      intense light
5        nice animal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['big dog', 'good food', 'dog and cat', 'little fish', 'intense light', 'nice cat']})
word = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']

out = dfa["a"].str.replace(f"({'|'.join(word)})", "animal", regex=True)
```

```
0           big animal
1            good food
2    animal and animal
3        little animal
4        intense light
5          nice animal
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   dfa['a'] = dfa['a'].str.replace(w, "animal")
```